# It is about plastic pollution

Tags: grammaticality

Avoid using plastic bottles. it harms our health, as it contains tiny harmfull substance called microplastic, which can led to hazardous diseases.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hazards can **lead** to diseases. I don't think diseases can be hazardous.